# Update query not updating?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am running this query in my database:

```
update search_products set further = 'fdfsfdf' where search_term LIKE '%1001%';
```

This affects 0 rows. So I tried this:

```
SELECT * from search_products where search_term LIKE '%1001%';
```

That returned exactly one row. So why cant I update the "further" column? The `search_products` table consists of some columns that just contain strings, no inique id or something. I get no errors, it just doesn't update.

Comment: begin transaction / commit ?

Comment: No, thats set to automatic in my IDE.

Comment: is the value of further already = 'fdfsfdf' ?

Comment: a trigger that rollbacks?

Comment: The column is all empty and there is no rollback for sure. I tried inserting something into other tables and that works.

Comment: No, it says "0 rows affected",thats all.

Comment: is a trigger on that table? (perhaps even a nocount in the trigger)

Comment: There is no trigger ...

Comment: can you change the like to a = (it has to still hit the select of course)

Comment: I solved it, it was the way I created the "further" column. Thanks for your ideas guys!

Comment: how did you create it?